# Spring Boot + Spring Security authorization success audit

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, audit

Has anyone managed to get Spring Boot w/ Spring Security to handle AuthorizedEvent's (i.e. for audit log)?

I have implemented the following application event listener:

```
@Component
public class AuthorizationSuccessAudit implements ApplicationListener<AuthorizedEvent> {

    private static Logger auditLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("audit");

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthorizedEvent event) {
        auditLogger.info("Authorization granted to user: {} - {}", event.getAuthentication().getName(), event.getConfigAttributes());
    }

}
```

and have a test MVC endpoint annotated with @PreAuthorize. I was expecting that the spring security grants would show up on the log. While this works for every other event I used (AuthenticationSuccessEvent, AuthenticationFailureEvent, AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) it does not for the AuthorizedEvent.

I tried browsing the Spring Boot source and it seems this event is not handled in [AuthorizationAuditListener.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/security/AuthorizationAuditListener.java), is this possibly a bug or am I hacking at it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

As per [spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-auditing.html), Use Spring Boot Actuator (audit framework for Spring Boot), and provide your own implementations of  AbstractAuthorizationAuditListener.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And something similar to this..

```
class TestAuthorizationAuditListener extends AbstractAuthorizationAuditListener { 

  @Override 
  public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) { 
  } 

  @Override 
  public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthorizationEvent event) { 
  } 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like spring boot can not realize that here you want to handle event.

Try to annotate method so that spring knows that here you want to handle event

```
@EventListener(value = {AuthorizedEvent.class})
public void onApplicationEvent(AuthorizedEvent event) {
        auditLogger.info("Authorization granted to user: {} - {}", event.getAuthentication().getName(), event.getConfigAttributes());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On successful authorization AuthorizedEvent should be triggered. make sure
FilterSecurityInterceptor should set setPublishAuthorizationSuccess true