# Log authorisation failures on Spring Boot RESTful API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In Spring Boot, what is the best approach to logging failed authorisation attemps at a RESTful API, i.e. in the below, if the user does not have the admin role, by default Spring will not log the failed attempt to access this method:

```java
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getVersion", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> printVersion() {
        logger.info("Received get request for version");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(applicationDetails.getAppVersion(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I've tried using an `ApplicationListener<AuthorizedEvent>`, and whilst a similar approach works for `ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent>`, it doesn't seem to work for `AuthorizedEvents`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426100/spring-boot-spring-security-authorization-success-audit ... this is related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong event, see [`AuthorizationFailureEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/event/AuthorizationFailureEvent.html):

> Indicates a secure object invocation failed because the principal could not be authorized for the request.
>
> This event might be thrown as a result of either an `AccessDecisionManager` or an `AfterInvocationManager`.